# Logical equivalences - show argument is valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

Using only the rules of inference and the logical equivalences, show that the
following argument is valid. You may assume that all the premises given are true.

Premises:

∧

→

s ∨ ( → )

¬ ∧

¬ ∧

Show: ¬p

So I've attempted the solution but I'm stuck and not sure what steps I should take next. Any input or help would be appreciated.

My solution so far:

1)  ∧

2)  →

3) s ∨ ( → )

4) ¬ ∧

5) ¬ ∧

6) ¬ by simplification (4)

7) ( → ) by disjunctive syllogism (3, 6)

8) ( → q) by hypothetical syllogism (2, 7)

9) ¬ by simplification (5)

10) ¬p by modus tollens (8, 9)

I'm trying to get rid of 1) and 6) left but I'm out of formulas I can think of to use. I thought maybe I could use addition somehow, but I'm not quite sure how that formula works. Like would that allow me to add any variable from the alphabet that I want or can I only use the variables that have already been defined?

Any thoughts or ideas on what steps I could take next would be appreciated.

Comment: Not clear... It works: you have derived $\lnot p$.

Comment: don't I have to get rid of the other premises? I thought I could only have 1 statement left.

Comment: Not necessarily; it means only that premise 1) is not needed for the argument.

Comment: 1 is indeed redundant. It follows from 4 and 5.

Comment: @PJK A *redundant premise* is merely one that is not required to entail the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{r\to q}~~\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{s\lor (p\to r)}~~\dfrac{\lnot s\land t}{\lnot s}{\tiny\text{simplification}}}{p\to r}{\tiny\text{disjunctive syl.}}}{p\to q}{\tiny\text{hypothetical syl.}}~~\dfrac{\lnot q\land u}{\lnot q}{\tiny\text{simplificaton}}}{\lnot p}{\tiny\text{modus tolens}}$$

---

You have correctly proven that $r \to q, s\lor (p\to r),\lnot s\land t,\lnot q\land u\vdash \lnot p$ and that was all you needed to do.

As the commenters have stated, the fact that you do not need premise $u\land t$ to derive $\lnot p$ is not a problem.   It is just a redundant premise.   You may have as many redundant premises as you wish.

$$m\lor n~,~u\land t~,~ r \to q~, s\lor (p\to r)~,\lnot s\land t~,\lnot q\land u\vdash \lnot p$$